# Unable to make/receive call from Lenovo TAB2 A10-30 (Lenovo TB2-X30L)

Tags: calls, sim-card, lenovo

I have a Lenovo TAB2 A10-30.

Model Number: Lenovo TB2-X30L
Serial Number: XXXXX

I can send and receive messages but unable make or receive a calls. I have downloaded and install many phone dialer apps from google play store, but it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [The voice call function is not available on this tablet, the SIM slot is there for DATA connection only](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and/Tab2-A10-30-voice-call/td-p/3532309).